# SourceTree filemerge quits immediately and creates 4 files. How to fix it?

Tags: macos, git, filemerge, atlassian-sourcetree

yesterday I could merge files in sourcetree with the external tool filemerge. Today, sourcetree wanted me to register me, and after my successful registration, I couldnt start filemerge.

When I choose "Launch external diff tool" from the contextmenu of a file, 4 files appear (Backup, base, local and remote) but filemerge quits immediately.

When I launch external diff, filemerge displays in the left /dev/null as source. How can I fix it? In preferences I choose filemerge as external diff tool. Have I to write the diff command for source tree manually, to give it the right local version of my file? How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem. If you have a merge conflict with a file that doesnt exist in one of the branches, filemerge quits immediately.

Comment: Please see this answer for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490804/156210

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with SourceTree where I tried to use "open in external merge tool". The FileMerge app exited immediately.

I did not have the merge conflict in a file that had been deleted one place or another, but in a single file that just changed.

I could not find the root cause but could work around using the command line:

```
git mergetool
```

This opened FileMerge just fine and I could resolved the conflict in FileMerge, save, quit, back to SourceTree, refresh, and the conflict was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue yesterday. I am using mac and having Xcode. I installed command line tools and mapped under Xcode. Also changed the diff to FileMerge in Sourcetree preferences. And I started getting it open.
Also sometimes even file appears in conflict list, but file might not have any conflict in it. It occurs due to the project tempfiles/cache or if you have intermediate commits. You still can double click that file, it will open in your IDE and you can verify. If there are no changes, mark as resolve and then move to stage.